# How to use Ninject's Named bindings in Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector, ninject.web.mvc

I have an MVC application using Ninject for DI and I'm planning to migrate the same to Simple Injector. But I couldn't find any alternatives for replacing the named binding of Ninject with Simple Injector.

Binding:

```
    kernel.Bind<IStudent>().To<Student1>().Named("Senior");
    kernel.Bind<IStudent>().To<Student2>().Named("Junior");
    kernel.Bind<IStudent>().To<Student3>().Named("Junior");
```

Controller:

```
public class StudentController
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<IStudent> _seniors;
  private readonly IEnumerable<IStudent> _juniors;
  public StudentController([named("Senior")] IEnumerable<IStudent> seniors,[named("Junior")] IEnumerable<IStudent> juniors)
  {
    _seniors=seniors;
    _juniors=juniors;
  }
}
```

I referred few links [How to use Ninject's Named bindings in Simple Injector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/389). But didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options:

**Option 1: Using the [named] attribute**

To achieve this, you will have to recreate the `NamedAttribute`, since this is not something that exists in Simple Injector, [for good reason](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/principles.html#vendor-lock-in).

You can make the following two conditional registrations for collections of students:

```
container.RegisterConditional<IEnumerable<IStudent>>(
    container.Collection.CreateRegistration<IStudent>(
        typeof(Student1)),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.GetCustomAttribute<namedAttribute>()?.Name == "Senior");

container.RegisterConditional<IEnumerable<IStudent>>(
    container.Collection.CreateRegistration<IStudent>(
        typeof(Student2),
        typeof(Student3)),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.GetCustomAttribute<namedAttribute>()?.Name == "Junior");
```

Each conditional registration wraps a `Registration` for an `IStudent` collection. The predicate filters the target, in this case the constructor argument, for the name of its `namedAttribute`.

**Option 2: Without the named attribute, by checking the argument name**

A simpler option, however, is to ditch the named attribute alltogether, and just filter based on the name of the constructor argument:

```
container.RegisterConditional<IEnumerable<IStudent>>(
    container.Collection.CreateRegistration<IStudent>(
        typeof(Student1)),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "seniors");

container.RegisterConditional<IEnumerable<IStudent>>(
    container.Collection.CreateRegistration<IStudent>(
        typeof(Student2),
        typeof(Student3)),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "juniors");
```

This registration is almost the same as with option 1, but now we filter based on the actual name of the argument, instead of based on its attribute.

**Option 3: By manually wiring StudentsController.**

An even simpler option is to revert from Auto-Wiring `StudentsController` to wiring it manually, as follows:

```
var seniors = container.Collection.Create<IStudent>(typeof(Student1));
var juniors = container.Collection.Create<IStudent>(typeof(Student2), typeof(Student3));
container.Register(() => new StudentController(seniors: seniors, juniors: juniors));
```

Here we request the Container to create the two collection of students, and create the registration for `StudentsController` where both collections are injected into.

Do note that in Simple Injector **collections are streams**. This means that the call to `Collection.Create` does **not** create the student instances, just a reference to a stream that will produce student instances when iterated. This means, the stream can be created at application startup, while the registrations lifestyles are preserved.

Also note that if you're calling `RegisterMvcControllers`, you will have to override the existing registration for this controller class. [This page](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) shows how to do this.

**Option 4: Changing the design. Make 'Level' a property of IStudent. Filter inside the controller.**

You can decide to change your design in a way that registration is simplified. Whether this is better highly depends on the context, so please take this with a grain of salt. However, when you add  a `Level` property, or something similar, to the `IStudent` interface that represents whether a student is a senior, and filter based on that *inside* the controller, your registrations are very much reduced to the following:

```
container.Collection.Register<IStudent>(typeof(Student1).Assembly);
```

Here we use Auto-Registration to search for all student implementations and register them all into one single collection.

In this case the `StudentController` will be left with a single constructor parameter, but you obviously moved the responsibility for filtering out of the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), into the controller.

```
public class StudentController
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStudent> _students;

    public StudentController(IEnumerable<IStudent> students)
    {
        _students = students;
    }
}
```